# Not able to connect secure sites ("https:") from android emulator

Tags: android, https, emulation

I am working on a android application, which is accessing a secured (https://) web service for some data. But I am facing some problem while testing the application in AVD emulator. The problem is that I am not been able to access the "https:" site neither from my application nor from the emulator browser. While I am trying to connect the site (in fact any secured website ) from the browser it's showing the error message as "**Data connectivity problem.
A secure connection could not be established.**". Though I can access the same websites from my window's web browsers.

According to my analysis the problem is with the privilege setting of the emulator. I am running the application on a corporate (my office) machine, where I don't have the admin rights (but I am a power user) and the machine is also behind the proxy. But as mentioned before I can access those secure sites from the machine's browsers, the only problem seems to be with the emulator accessibility.

I tried to test the same code from my personal laptop and as expected it's working perfectly.

Can somebody please help me out to find out the solution for this? How can I access a secured site from the emulator? FYI I am using eclipse Helios & Android 2.1

Please let me know if you need any more information from my side.

Comment: i think you need some ssl certificates to connect secure sites

Comment: so the application works in the emulator on your laptop? was that on the same network or a different one?

Comment: Hi @ChiragRaval!! I tried that.. But the problem still exists. It gives me following error. java.io.IOException: SSL handshake failure: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:585 
0xaf586674:0x00000000)

Comment: Hi @dldnh !! No I am using my laptop in a different network.

Comment: If you are able to use your laptop on the same network, you'll learn whether it is the network or the other development environment that's at fault.

Comment: Hi @dldnh I can't do that. I am not allowed to use my personal computer to my office network. Anything else I can do??

Comment: that's understandable, but unfortunate because you don't really know whether the problem is with the development environment or just some kind of restriction inherent in your network/proxy environment.